# How to check the cycles in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have the Prolog predicates:

```
gen(c1, c2). 
gen(c2, c1).
gen(c2, c3).
gen(c3, c1).
```

I want to write a rule to check that there are no cycles in the gen/2 predicates. How should I write this rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At beginning we will try to consider it from top to bottom.

What mean that there is no cycle?

~False that it has any cycle.

What mean that it has any cycle ?

~I can go from one node to same node, through other nodes.

How can I check that I can go to the same node through other nodes?

~ Append to the empty list nodes, that I can go from start one, and than add other nodes that I can archive from these nodes (and don't add **NODES THAT I ALREADY HAVE IN LIST!!!!!!!!!**)

```
node(X) :- 
        gen(X,_) ; gen(_,X).

canGoTo(X,N, Nodes) :- 
        member(X2, [X|Nodes]), gen(X2, X1),
        \+ member(X1, Nodes), 
        canGoTo(X, N, [X1|Nodes]).

canGoTo(_,N,N).

canGoTo(X,Nodes) :- canGoTo(X,Nodes,[]).

canGoToSelf(X) :- canGoTo(X,Nodes), member(X,Nodes),!.

isCycle() :- node(X) , canGoToSelf(X),!. 

noCycles() :- \+ isCycle().
```